# Click event not firing with overflow: scroll

Tags: javascript, android, css, cordova

This problem occurs in the stock browser included with at least Android 4.1.2 (not Mobile Chrome) and the WebView component in a cordova-based android app we're building.

I've built a page with a fixed header at the top of the view that contains a horizontally scrollable set of tabs with the basic DOM and inline CSS below, and click handlers attached to each of the tabs are not firing.

```
<html>
...
<body>
    <div>
        <header class="navheader" style="position: fixed; z-index: 1000;">
            <h1>....</h1>
            <nav style="width: 100%; overflow: scroll; -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;">
                <div class="tabs">
                    <div class="tab"><a href="...">...</a></div>
                    <div class="tab"><a href="...">...</a></div>
                    <div class="tab"><a href="...">...</a></div>
                    <div class="tab"><a href="...">...</a></div>
                    <div class="tab"><a href="...">...</a></div>
                    <div class="tab"><a href="...">...</a></div>
                    ...
                </div>
            </nav>
        </header>
        <section>
            ...
        </section>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I've tried attaching a click handler in several ways with jQuery, such as:

```
$('body').on('click', 'header .tab', function(event){ ... });
```

or

```
$('.tabs .tab').on('click', function(event){ ... });
```

along with variations on the selector like 'header .tabs a', 'header .tabs .tab a', and 'header a'. I also tried:

```
$('.tabs .tab a').each(function(i) { this.onclick=function(){ ... }; });
```

and adding the onclick attribute to each `a` tag:

```
<div class="tab"><a href="..." onclick="alert('hi');">...</a></div>
```

None these worked.

Using this code, though:

```
$('body').on('click', function(event){
    console.log("Click" + $(event.target).attr('class'));
});
```

The click event will print 'navheader' or whatever is behind the element with 'overflow: scroll' set. Adjusting the z-index for each tab, the tabs container, and/or the nav elem had no effect on this either.

Removing 'overflow: scroll' from the CSS alleviates the problem and the events fire with any of the methods for registering a handler (the '-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch' seemed to have no effect). But then I obviously lose the ability to scroll horizontally. Thus, it seems like elements with scrollable inner content are in some way removed from the event bubbling hierarchy. It also works in Mobile Chrome and all things iOS.

Has anyone found a work-around?

Also, `webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);` is declared in for WebView.

Comment: I'm having the same problem and would kill for a solution that doesn't involve manually processing the x and y coordinates of the click.

Comment: I'm falling into the same issue but I see that `touchstart` and `touchend` events would help in these cases, but I'm not sure

Answer (score 0):

I ended up essentially doing my own hit detection:

```
$('body').on('click', '.navheader', function(event) {
    var $nav = $('nav'), x = event.pageX || event.clientY, y = event.pageY || event.clientY;
    y -= $(window).scrollTop();
    // Because the nav bar takes up the whole width for us
    if (y > $nav[0].offsetTop && y < $nav[0].offsetTop + $nav.outerHeight()) {
        var scroll_left = $nav[0].scrollLeft, click_offset = scroll_left + x,
            $tabs = $nav.find(".tab");
        // Since each tab has a different width
        $tabs.each(function(i) {
            if (click_offset >= this.offsetLeft && click_offset < this.offsetLeft + this.offsetWidth) {
                // Hurray, we clicked a tab, do something like .click()
            }
        });
    }
});
```